# What's a good iScroll alternative that supports iOS, Android, WP8 and pull-to-refresh functionality?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, html, iscroll

I am looking for an alternative to iScroll for scrolling inside div's.

It needs to support these OS's:

- iOS
- Android
- WP8

And I also need pull-to-refresh functionality.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After days of evaluation, I came to the conclusion that there is no framework or library out there that fits all my needs. So, the only choice left was to create a custom solution for each operating system. This is what I came up with:

- **iOS** < 5: iScroll
- **iOS** >= 5: Native scrolling via CSS properties `overflow-y:auto` and `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch`. Pull-to-refresh via https://github.com/dantipa/pull-to-refresh-js
- **Android**: iScroll
- **WP8**: Native scrolling via `overflow-y:auto`. Own implementation for pull-to-refresh (very tricky).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure whether all the OS's are supported, but give it a try (it also has pull-to-refresh): http://zynga.github.com/scroller/

Also http://labs.ft.com/articles/ft-scroller/ is worth of trying (supports your OS requirements), although I'm not aware of whether there's way to achieve pull-to-refresh easily.

Comment: Nope, I tried the examples on both pages on my WP8 device (HTC 8x) and they both do not work. So far I noticed that `overflow-y:auto;` works best on WP8 devices but that would mean I'd need extra handling for WP8 and I'd have to implement pull-to-refresh on my own.

Comment: @Timo did the Zynga scroller not work at all on WP8, or was it just the pull-to-refresh?

Comment: @Patrick Sorry, I don't remember. You'll have to try on your own :-(

Comment: @Timo If only I could own one of every version of every device/browser/OS : (